# WebView equivalent in Java ME

Tags: java-me, nokia

I am working on developing a hybrid mobile application, we already have a mobile interface for the application and we used WebView on Android to give users the sense of a stand-alone application.
The question is how can I do that on, let's say, Nokia phones?

-- Thanks;

Answer (score 3):

If you can use LWUIT there is HTMLComponent: http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.4/LWUIT_Developer_Guide_HTML/bbjidhgf.html.

The most simple use case of HTMLComponent is rendering rich text:

```
HTMLComponent htmlC = new HTMLComponent(null);
htmlC.setBodyText("Hello <b>bold text</b>");
```

Comment: According to this blog entry http://lwuit.blogspot.com.br/2009/10/bidi-oh-so-many-changes.html you should call UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel().setRTL(true). Did you do this?

Comment: We didn't do that, we will test it and see! Thanks

Comment: @TelmoPimentelMota I know Stack Overflow is not the forum for this, but if you're still able to do JavaME development projects on LWUIT, I would love to talk to you. I see no other way of contacting you...

Comment: @theglossy1 I just updated my profile adding my LinkedIn page. Can you reach me there?